# Img src ternary operator not displaying image

Tags: angular, image, src

I'm trying to use a ternary operator in angular for two image sources based on a condition. I'm getting no errors but the images are not displaying.

```
<img
          class="rounded-circle z-depth-2 mb-2"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          alt="profile picture"
          [attr.src]="user.user_profile_picture !== null ? 'http://localhost:8000/storage/profile_images/' +
            user.user_profile_picture.image : 'http://localhost:8000/storage/profile-picture.png'"
          data-holder-rendered="true"
        />
      </div>
```

Am I making a basic mistake here?

Comment: use just `[src]`, not `[attr.src]` and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just [src], not [attr.src].

Any way, due you don't get the image from your angular proyect (from src/asstes or similar), I'm not completly sure if you have to "sanitize" this url's before.

Try and comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just updated it to [src] and same result.

Comment: JUST FOR TESTING: put a jpg image (renamed as xxx.jpg) in your assets folder (for instance: '/src/assets/xxx.jpg'), and change your code to this:  [src]="user.user_profile_picture != null ? 'assets/xxx.jpg' : 'assets/xxx.jpg'   (for now, use != instead of !==)

Comment: I've just rebuilt the application after updating the [src] and it's now decided to work.